# Select Least with sql query with depended statment on mulitple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not even sure how to ask this question... but here goes. i want to run a query that selects least of 13 columns when the value of the column is greater than O ( i got that part) but i want to check a corresponding column for each column ( price, qty) so if qty =0 do not include the price column associated with that quantity in the least query. so here is what i have so far

```
**SELECT isbn13,  LEAST(
IF(Price1,Price1,999999),
IF(Price2,Price2,999999),
IF(Price3,Price3,999999),
IF(Price4,Price4,999999),
IF(Price5,Price5,999999),
IF(Price6,Price6,999999),
IF(Price7,Price7,999999),
IF(Price8,Price8,999999),
IF(Price9,Price9,999999),
IF(Price10,Price10,999999),
IF(Price11,Price11,999999),
IF(Price12,Price12,999999),
IF(Price13,Price13,999999),) as theMin

FROM table
where po='po1'**
```

the part i need to ad is where Price1>0 and Qty1 >0 use Price1 in least Statement and so on and so forth for Price1-13 and Qty1-13. If i am making this too hard please i am open to any solution.

i have tried adding IF(Price13,Price13,999999) and QTY13>0, (no dice)
also  where po='po1' and (Qty1>0 or Qty2>0....) is not what i want

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag, because the code is clearly not SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    isbn13,
    LEAST(
        IF (price1 > 0 AND qty1 > 0, price1, 999999),
        IF (price2 > 0 AND qty2 > 0, price2, 999999)
        etc.
    )
FROM table_name
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/130cb7/1